# What is dimension of annihilator of general subset of vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Definitions:

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbf{F}$ and $U$ a subset of $V$.
The annihilator of $U$, denoted $U^0$ is $$U^0=\{\varphi:V\rightarrow \mathbf{F} \ \ | \ \varphi|_U = 0 \}.$$

Motivation:
In general, we know that the annihilator $U^0$ is a subspace of $V$. 
When $U$ is a subspace of $V$, we also know that
$$\text{dim } U^0 = \text{dim } V - \text{dim } U.$$
I'm trying to gain an intuition/ understanding of the annihilator of a general subset.  That is why I am asking this question.

Question:

What is the dimension of $U^0$ when $U$ is not a subspace?
As a more specific example, what is the dimension of the annihilator of the unit sphere $\mathbf{S} \subset \mathbf{R}^3$ in 3-space?

Idea:

Maybe it should be related to the co-dimension of the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $U$.  I know this is easy to determine, and it seems like a linear functional that annihilates one of this subspace should annihilate $U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By linearity, if a linear map $L$ vanishes on a vector $v$ (that is, $L(v)=0$) then it has to vanish on the whole line $\Bbb R v$ (called the line "spanned by $v$").

Therefore $U^0=(\operatorname{Span}U)^0$ where $\operatorname{Span}U$ is the smallest linear subspace that contains $U$. From then on you can apply your formula, since $\operatorname{Span}U$ is a linear subspace.

So all you have to do is understand what the subspace spanned by the sphere is.